# DIVs are moving from their positions when zooming out of the page

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, css-position

So basically my problem is when I zoom in-out of the page, some DIVs move out from their position which causes my layout to break. I used the position relative and absolute properties as well as used % instead px as my units in positioning. I've gone through some articles saying that it's not favorable to use position absolute and that this was an expected behavior but I couldn't seem to find an answer to my question. I also tried find a way to do it using CSS Flexbox but i couldn't find a direct answer to my problem.

My expected layout should be something like https://snipboard.io/Mr8sNv.jpg but as I said before, it breaks when zooming in/out.

Here is my HTML.

```
        <div class="Container">
            <div class="background">                  
                <div class="Space"></div>
                <p class="Branding_Design">BRANDING & DESIGN</p>
                <div class="Project_One">Project One</div>
                <div class="SliderBOX"></div>
                <div style="position:absolute; right: 8%; top: 59%;">
                    <div class="ProjectDetailsContainer">
                        <p class="Project_Details">PROJECT DETAILS</p>                 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="position:absolute; right: 12%; top: 62.5%;">
                    <div class="ViewSlidesContainer">
                        <p class="View_Slides">VIEW SLIDES</p>                            
                    </div>
                </div>                    
             </div>                  
        </div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.Container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 721px;
}

.background {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.Space {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.SliderBOX{
    height: 525px;
    width: 50%;
    background: yellow;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.Branding_Design {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  color: #f7ac53;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 39%;
  left: 12%;
}

.Project_One {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Merriweather";
  font-size: 39px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 14%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ProjectDetailsContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.Project_Details {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 11px;
}


.ViewSlidesContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.View_Slides {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

I also included my code in jsfiddle in order to make it easier to go through my code
https://jsfiddle.net/wa3bLx1h/22/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your expected layout?

Comment: @huanfeng This is my expected layout https://snipboard.io/Mr8sNv.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think believe the code below, is what you're looking for correct? Flex-box would the solution to remedy this problem. I would suggest just go thru MDN tutorials and mess around with each properties of flex-box. Your problem helped me understand Parent and Child containers better now.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="background">
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="textCon1">
      <div class="p-text-1">
        <p class="brandingDesign"> BRANDING & DESIGN</p>
      </div>
      <div class="p-text-2">
        <p class="projectOne">Project One</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sliderBox"></div>
    <div class="projectDetailContainer">
      <div class="p-text-3">
        <p class="projectDetails"> PROJECT DETAILS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="viewSlideContainer">
        <p class="viewSlides">VIEW SLIDES</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 721px;
  width: 100%;
}
.background {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.sliderBox {
  height: 525px;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
}
.textCon1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.brandingDesign {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  color: #f7ac53;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.projectOne {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Merriweather";
  font-size: 39px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.projectDetailContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.projectDetails {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.viewSlides {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is a good solution to the problem.